# UITableView Reusable issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` cell should be marked.But when i am scrolling down the `UITableView` checkmark is also effecting reusable cells of `UITableView`.How solve this issue?

Comment: You need to track the cell selection state and set/reset the accessory in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Cell reusage was already discussed hundred of times.

Comment: i want to know how to track those values.not about cell reusage

Comment: i tried both the examples but i am unable to do thats y i placed this question back.

Comment: The listed duplicates show several methods for tracking selection state. If you are having difficulty implementing those solutions then you should ask a new question that shows your code and describes the specific issue tap hat you are having.

Answer (score -1):

Since your cells will be reused when scrolling, make sure to initialize all aspects of your cell *in all cases*. Therefore, don't forget to initialize your cell to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` when you do not need a check mark.